# How to quote multiple lines

Tags: support

If I would like to quote multiple lines together, do I have to add ">" at the beginning of every line and two spaces at the end of each line? Is there a way similar to [quote] ... [\quote]. By the way, what is [quote] ... [\quote] used for, and why it does not work here?

Similarlly, is there something as convenient as to [code] ... [\code] to quote a snippet of code?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. To get quotes highlight the text and press "Ctrl+Q" (Q for quote).
2. For a code block, highlight the text and press "Ctrl+K" (K for Code).

Comment: Or use buttons with quote and zeros and ones.